# Collection Radio Buttons for form exhibiting strange behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm experiencing some odd behavior using the `collection_radio_buttons` helper for forms in Rails 6. I expected the following code to just have two radio buttons labeled "true" and "false" that would return their respective boolean values, but for some reason it labels the "true" button correctly but the "false" button is labeled "Unpaid false". What am I missing?

```
    <% t_or_f = [true, false] %>

    <div class="pb-3">
        <%= form.label :unpaid, "This was an unpaid position." %>
        <div>
          <%= form.collection_radio_buttons :unpaid, t_or_f, :to_s, :itself %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have now implemented this using just individual radio buttons for each value, however I was curious about the above described behavior.

Comment: have you tried `<%= form.collection_radio_buttons :unpaid, t_or_f, :to_s, :to_s %>`?

Answer (score 0):

Elements in your collection must be strings.

Just change

```
<% t_or_f = [true, false] %>
```

by

```
<% t_or_f = ['true', 'false'] %>
```